# How to store strings and count into an array in C language

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

I have the following data in text file

```
we are studying hard
we can go out for vacation
I can have fun!!
I can have fun!!

fun!
```

Desired output

```
#1  we       2
#2  are      1
#3  studying 1
#4  hard     1
#5  can      3
#6  go       1
#7  out      1
#8  for      1
#9  vacation 1
#10 I        2
#11 have     2
#12 fun      3
```

I have to show the each word and its repeated times.

I tried the following code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
#define MAX_LEN 1000
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char data[MAX_LEN];

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    char *filename = argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return(1);
    }
    int line = 0;

    char c;
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n')
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            line++;
            printf("%c", c);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < line; i++)
        printf("%s", data[i]);

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code is printing the values but I am not able to find the count. Can any one please suggest me to correct my code. I am new to Coding but eager to learn. Thanks!!

I am expecting to find the count of repeated chars in the file.

Comment: You've got some extra single backticks in your question's markdown formatting.  Just use a triple backtick at the beginning and end of your code block to mark it as code (no need to also indent)

Comment: Hi, you will need to use strcmp() on each word read -- to compare against each and every one of the previous words read.  If the strings match, then that is the 2nd (or higher) time the word has been seen.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems:

- `c` should be defined as an `int` for the test `while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)` to operate reliably
- you increment `line` on each separator but never store anything into the array `data`
- `printf("%s", data[i]);` passes a `char` where `printf` expects a string pointer (`char *` pointing to a null terminated array).

You should instead follow these steps:

- read one word at a time, skipping non characters,
- search the word in an array of words seen so far
- if found, increment the same entry in an array of `int`
- if not found, add a new entry for the word and set the initial count to `1`.

At end of file, output the counts and words.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_WORD_LEN  100
#define MAX_WORD_COUNT 1000

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char word[MAX_WORD_LEN + 1];
    char *words[MAX_WORD_COUNT];
    int counts[MAX_WORD_COUNT];
    int n = 0;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    const char *filename = argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    int i = 0;
    for (;;) {
        int c = getc(file);
        if (isalpha(c)) {
            if (i < MAX_WORD_LEN)
                word[i++] = (char)c;
        } else {
            if (i > 0) {
                // handle the word
                word[i] = '\0';

                for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    if (!strcmp(word, words[i])) {
                        counts[i] += 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (i == n) {
                    if (i >= MAX_WORD_COUNT) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "too many words\n");
                        break;
                    }
                    counts[n] = 1;
                    words[n++] = strdup(word);
                }
            }
            i = 0;
            if (c == EOF)
                break;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("#%d\t%s\t%d\n", i + 1, words[i], counts[i]);
        free(words[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I got what you are saying but can you pls help with pasting full code

Comment: @klp: I did and you should study it to learn how to do things.  Justing pasting it for your assignment would teach you nothing.

Comment: @Nithyasarathi: what do you mean?